# Can I add AJAX code(animated files) in header section of blogger blogs?

Tags: ajax, blogger

I have created a health blog using blogger. I want to add AJAX code in their header section.

Can this be done? How would I get started?

Answer (score 0):

Layout -> edit html in blog settings.
HTML is fully editable, so it's possible to add <script> tags.